# Multiple IF conditions inside filter

Tags: javascript, if-statement, filter

I want to filter a table (2d array) together with IF condition (depending on HTML select value) and use this code

```
transportRegFiltered = transportReg.filter(r => 
          {if(lugarDe.value == "TODOS"){return true} else {return (r[6] == lugarDe.value)}    
          })
```

with 1 condition it works but I need to have several ones. Smth like

```
transportRegFiltered = transportReg.filter(r => 
          {if(lugarDe.value == "TODOS"){return true} else {return (r[6] == lugarDe.value)} 
           if(lugarA.value == "TODOS"){return true} else {return (r[7] == lugarA.value)}
          }
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Think through the logic.  You perform your first if/else.  If the `if` happens, you return.  If the `else` happens, you return.  It cannot ever reach the second if/else pair.  You need to rethink what you are trying to do.

Comment: The first if and else always return a value from there. So use `if/else if/else` ?

Comment: use `||` `"or"` instead of `if` and `else`

Comment: I understand if then else logic. But here what I am trying to do is to have several filter conditions but each one of them can take place only if a specific SELECT value is chosen. If no - filter just should avoid it.
And I have several SELECT which filters specific table column this way

Comment: do you have an example of **all** values, you like to check?

Answer (score 1):

You can return all the condition using OR operator. Because

```
if(A) { return true; } else { return B; }
if(C) { return true; } else { return D; }
```

Translates to

```
return A || B || C || D;
```

So you can write something like this inside the filter,

```
return ( lugarDe.value == "TODOS" || r[6] == lugarDe.value || lugarA.value == "TODOS" || r[7] == lugarA.value ... and all the other conditions );
```

Comment: not sure how it translates to `A || B || C || D` when it is only `A || B`

Comment: The intended goal is presumably the translation.  The currently existing flawed logic is obviously not that. @epascarello

Answer (score 0):

I am not really clear what you want the if statements to do exactly, but one stab at it would be check the values and then checking the other conditions with ORs.

```
var isTodos = [lugarDe.value, lugarA.value].includes("TODOS");
return isTodos || r[6] == lugarDe.value || r[7] == lugarA.value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to apply each filter independently if the condition for that filter is taken? In that case you can cascade the filters:

```
transportRegFiltered = transportReg
  .filter((r) => {
    if (lugarDe.value == "TODOS") {
      return true;
    } else {
      return r[6] == lugarDe.value;
    }
  })
  .filter((r) => {
    if (lugarA.value == "TODOS") {
      return true;
    } else {
      return r[7] == lugarA.value;
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take an array for checking the values.

```
transportRegFiltered = transportReg.filter(r => {
    const values = [lugarDe.value, lugarA.value];
    return values.includes("TODOS") || values.some((v, i) => v === r[i + 6]);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

ok I did it in most simple and direct way. Just wanted to find some fancy one...
I just looped through all options of 3 inputs and assigned different filters for each combination including or excluding relevant filter condition

```
var transportRegFiltered;    
    if(lugarDe.value == "TODOS" && lugarA.value == "TODOS" && lotIdSearch.value.length == 0){
                    transportRegFiltered = transportReg} 
                    
                  else if (lugarDe.value == "TODOS" && lugarA.value == "TODOS" && lotIdSearch.value.length > 0) {
                     transportRegFiltered = transportReg.filter(r => (r[5]).toString().toLowerCase().startsWith(lotIdSearchValue))}
                     
                  else if (lugarDe.value !== "TODOS" && lugarA.value == "TODOS" && lotIdSearch.value.length == 0) {
                     transportRegFiltered = transportReg.filter(r => r[6] == lugarDe.value)}
                     
                  else if (lugarDe.value == "TODOS" && lugarA.value !== "TODOS" && lotIdSearch.value.length == 0) {
                     transportRegFiltered = transportReg.filter(r => r[7] == lugarA.value)}
                  
                  else if (lugarDe.value !== "TODOS" && lugarA.value !== "TODOS" && lotIdSearch.value.length == 0) {
                     transportRegFiltered = transportReg.filter(r => r[6] == lugarDe.value && r[7] == lugarA.value)}
                     
                  else if (lugarDe.value !== "TODOS" && lugarA.value == "TODOS" && lotIdSearch.value.length > 0) {
                     transportRegFiltered = transportReg.filter(r => r[6] == lugarDe.value && (r[5]).toString().toLowerCase().startsWith(lotIdSearchValue))}
                  
                  else if (lugarDe.value == "TODOS" && lugarA.value !== "TODOS" && lotIdSearch.value.length > 0) {
                     transportRegFiltered = transportReg.filter(r => r[7] == lugarA.value && (r[5]).toString().toLowerCase().startsWith(lotIdSearchValue))}
                     
                 else if (lugarDe.value !== "TODOS" && lugarA.value !== "TODOS" && lotIdSearch.value.length > 0) {
                     transportRegFiltered = transportReg.filter(r => r[6] == lugarDe.value && r[7] == lugarA.value && (r[5]).toString().toLowerCase().startsWith(lotIdSearchValue))}
```